# How to consume all RabbitMQ messages other than specified in routing_key?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

RabbitMQ allows distribute messages over several queues based on routing_key matching. For exchange of type='topic' one can specify wildcard symbols which allows more flexible filtering (than in case of type='direct' exchange), they are:

```
* (star) can substitute for exactly one word.
# (hash) can substitute for zero or more words.
```

E.g., for queue with routing_key='A.B.*' the exchange is pushing all the messages with routing_key of the patterns 'A.B.A', 'A.B.1', 'A.B.XXX', etc.

In my use case I need two queues bound to the same exchange, one queue receives all messages with routing_key='A.B.A' and another queue receives all other messages which is not matching to 'A.B.A'. It is not a big deal to do it for the first queue but I cannot really find anything in tutorials which helps me with the second queue...

Please, would be nice to have an example in python + pika library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you clarify your requirement of `bound to the same exchange`?

If it's "just" having the messages pushed through the same exchange instead, you could check out [alternate exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html)

Basically it's a configuration on your "main" exchange which states that any message that doesn't match **any** of the bindings to queues bound to it will be transferred to an *alternate exchange* (can be of different type) for processing.

A simple setup would be to have that alternate exchange of type fanout, routing all of those *unbound* messages to a given queue.

Comment: Thanks, the alternate exchange solves the issue though an extra exchange is required. Why they didn't provide an extra tutorial for such useful feature here https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html ...